# iAd bottom UITableViewController not showing ads

Tags: objective-c, tableview, iad

I have a `UISplitViewController` and I have the `MasterViewController` with a `UITableViewController`.
I want to add an iAd at the bottom of the view. I think I have achieved this, but there are no ad's showing.

```
self.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.adBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50);
[self.view addSubview:self.adBannerView];

//set proper bottom inset depending on your banner height
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);

adBannerView.delegate = self;
```

I have implemented the delegate methods:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
        if (adBannerView.superview == nil)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:adBannerView];
        }

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
        // banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad MLEFT");
    NSLog(@"MLEFT Error :%@",error);
    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        // banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }

}
```

But the ad is not showing. Also not after a few hours waiting. In another view, the ad is loaded.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have added iAd.framework in **Build Phases => Link Binary With Libraries.
2. In case you are using storyboard, check if ADBannerView is not behind any other view. (I suggest try to put at **0,0 position** in front of all views for testing)